# Simple script to find "lowest" available domain name

Tags: algorithm, dns

I need a script to find out what is the lowest available domain name with a give TLD (say .com, .info, or .net).

For example, [1000423.com](http://www.who.is/whois/1000423.com/) is free but [1000.com](http://www.who.is/whois/1000.com/) is taken.

Probably my spammiest question so far.

**NOTE**

I mean "lowest" domain name numerically (i.e. 1.com, 2.com, 3.com, ..., *n*.com, *n+1*.com, ...) and not shortest as in String.length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your web-capable language of choice:

1. Ask the user for a top-level domain name.
2. i <- 0.
3. Send out an HTTP GET to a registrar to see if "i.(tld)" is taken.
4. If it's not taken, notify the user and quit.
5. i <- i + 1.
6. Go to step 2.

You may need to add a loop delay to avoid the registrar thinking that you're trying to do a DOS attack.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no central repository saying that a certain domain name is or isn't for sale. You'll have to look up a domain name and see if it's owned by any of the major domain name vendors (GoDaddy, etc.)

Comment: I meant lowest **numerically** and not shortest by string length - I'll fix that.